# What is the fastest way to get the number of rows in a csv file?

Tags: c++, csv, file-handling

What is the best way to get the number of rows in a CSV file? I have a large CSV file (1 GB) and iterating through the whole file using getline takes forever.
Here is what I've tried:

```
string s; 
int RowCount=0;

ifstream in("sample.csv");

while(!in.eof()) {
    getline(in, s);
    RowCount ++;
}

cout << "Rows: "<<RowCount;

in.close();
```

Is there a way to determine the number of lines in a text file without opening it?

Comment: *Is there a way to determine the number of lines in a text file without opening it?* Hardly; not unless you have some information. For example: a fixed row length or some sort of header/metadata.

Comment: No there's no way to check the contents of a file in any way without opening it.

Comment: Also, see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5605125)

Comment: Try `in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` instead of `std::getline`

Comment: I can feel a potential [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. Why do you need the row count in the first place? You are not going to allocate some fixed size array or anything, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can't determine the number of lines in the file without opening it. Unless each line is of fixed length, in which case you could simply divide the file size by the length of a line. Otherwise you actually have to read through the entire file counting the lines.

This should be about as fast as you can get:

```
std::ifstream in("sample.csv");

std::size_t RowCount = 0;

char buff[4096]; // larger = faster (within limits)

while(in.read(buff, sizeof(buff)) || in.gcount())
    RowCount += std::count(buff, buff + in.gcount(), '\n');

std::cout << "Rows: " << RowCount;
```

It reads the file in chunks into a buffer and counts the number of line ending markers `'\n'`. The larger the buffer, the more efficient it should be.

Comment: I can't find a reference atm, so I may just be crazy, but I'm fairly certain I've encountered some more efficient line counting algorithms in past years.. still upvoting this though.

Comment: @JesperJuhl To be honest I really can't see how a program can discover how many line-ending markers a file contains without reading all of it. The only way I can imagine improving on the speed of this would be to use lower level, system specific calls in order to cut out any potential intermediate buffering.

Comment: makes sense. I just have this nagging memory. I'm probably just mixing things up though.